# swift : smoothing translation of UIView exactly as iOS control panel (following user finger, using pan)

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to move a UIView from bottom to top with my finger just like the control center in iOS, and especially with the same movement "smoothing" as the control center in iOS (velocity looks bounded, when velocity is high, no need to go far with the finger to make the UIView moving to the top etc.). 
My question is : is there any preset or librairy i could use instead of doing my custom and not precise calculations myself ? I'm not very good at making this "smooth" effect, and maybe UIKit provide something to use in panGestureRecognizer handler to smooth a movement translation following sender.translation ?

Now my gestureRecognizer handler is :

```
var y = sender.translation(in: view).y
let vy = sender.velocity(in: view).y

// we need to move constraintHeightInfoView.constant
// this is the height of my "ios control panel"

// i noticed the ios control panel move less if user tries 
// to move it out of screen bounds, so i'm first calculating 
// how much we are out of bound, in order to know "how much" 
// we will reduce velocity
var outofbound:CGFloat = 0
if(constraintHeightInfoView.constant < minH)
{
    outofbound = minH - constraintHeightInfoView.constant
}
else if(constraintHeightInfoView.constant > maxH)
{
    outofbound = constraintHeightInfoView.constant - maxH
}

// velocity target in pt/s
// i noticed the smooth effect in ios control panel includes 
// a velocity bound : if user pulls very fast the control panel, 
// it is not following the user finger, but it's a bit slower : 
// so there is a "vmax". When user release, i guess this vmax is 
// used for the final animation too 
let vtarget:CGFloat = 300 

print("\(y), \(vy), ofb : \(outofbound)")


// Here i'm lost : im trying to say : 
// if velocity above vtarget, reduce y so it match vtarget
if(abs(vy) > vtarget) {
    let dv = abs(vy) - vtarget
    y = // ????
}





switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed :
    if case .began = sender.state {
        initialY = constraintHeightInfoView.constant
    }

    let newH = (expandInfoViewInitialY ?? minH) - y

    constraintHeightInfoView.constant = newH

    view.layoutIfNeeded()

case .ended :

    let heightTo:CGFloat
    let blurAlpha:CGFloat
    // 250 is the middle between top position and 
    // bottom position : if velocity is high, dont need to pull 
    // a lot to proceed the final release animation
    // if vy is 3000, even very small movement proceed the 
    // animation. Otherwise, if very slow movement, 
    // user needs to go at least at the middle between top and bottom (250)
    if(constraintHeightInfoView.constant > 250 - (-vy/300) * 50)
    {
        heightTo = maxH
        blurAlpha = 1
    }
    else
    {
        heightTo = minH
        blurAlpha = 0
    }


    // time of animation depends on remaining distance to bottom/top
    let dy = abs(self.constraintHeightInfoView.constant - heightTo)


    var t = dy / vtarget

    print("end : d:\(dy), t:\(t)")
    UIView.animate(withDuration:TimeInterval(t), delay:0,options:[.curveEaseOut], animations :{
        self.constraintHeightInfoView.constant = heightTo
        self.viewInfoBlurEffect.alpha = blurAlpha
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

default :
    break
}
```

With all of this, my transition is still far from looking like Apple control center's one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a much more satisfactory experience if you set this up as an animation from bottom to top and from top to bottom that looks the way you want it. Now "freeze" it and hook into it from a pan gesture recognizer by way of UIViewPropertyAnimator. This makes it an *interactive animation*.

This will allow you, for example, just to "finish" the animation if the user drags more than a certain amount. And you'll be able to do both tap-to-dismiss and drag-to-dismiss though the same animator.

Comment: It is not permitted for you to ask for a third-party tutorial or example, but once you have the notion "interactive animation" in your head, you will find that there are lots of examples. Like this one: https://github.com/nathangitter/interactive-animations

Comment: Thanks I just didn’t know this notion of  “interactive animation”. Your link looks great Im trying to understand their code. But it seems I still need to feel confortable with loads of maths formulas haha ..